# parse output like id:name/class:id to id:class:name with bash awk

Tags: bash, awk

I do a curl on a xml file.
The output like :

```
name
  uuid3 - name
  uuid1 - name
  uuid2 - name
class
  class - uuid3
  class - uuid2
  class - uuid1
```

I need to sort this pattern like :

```
uuid1 - class - name
uuid2 - class - name
uuid3 - class - name
```

I think the best way to do the stuff is `awk`, but all solution are good.

thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=" - "} 
            {gsub(/ /,"",$1); gsub(/ /,"",$2)} 
        c==1{a[$1]=$2} 
        c==2{print $2,$1,a[$2]} 
       NF==1{c++}' file

uuid3 - class - name
uuid2 - class - name
uuid1 - class - name
```

order of entries is based on second block.

**Explanation**

'c' is the block count, incremented when there is only one field (header).  When processing the first block (`c==1`) it creates a map (awk array) to associate field one and two.  In the second block processing  (`c==2`) prints second field, first field and looked up value from the map for the first field.  The first section of the code removes the extra spaces for the look up to work.

Comment: A lot more eloquent than my solution for sure.

Comment: can you explain me in details that lines please: c==1 { a[$1]=$2 }, c==2 { print a[$2],$1,$2 }, NF==1 { c++ } ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming *'class'* were a literal constant and we can use it as a reference, then this would work:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="
name
    uuid1 - one
    uuid2 - two
    uuid3 - three
class
    class - uuid1
    class - uuid2
    class - uuid3
"

# Get all lines where the first token is 'class'
class=`echo -e "${str}" | grep -P "\tclass"`

# Count all of the lines...
lines=`echo -e "${class}" | wc -l`

echo -e "lines = ${lines}\n"

strout=

# Loop through the result and extract each individual line...
l=1
while [ $l -le $lines ]; do
    line=`echo -e "${class}" | head -n ${l} | tail -n 1`

    # Now, token 3 will be the unique uuid token...
    uuid=`echo -e "$line" | awk '{print $3}'`

    # We can use this unique uuid to reference the name lines...
    n=`echo -e "${str}" | grep -P "\t$uuid" | awk '{print $3}'`

    strout="${strout}\n${uuid} - class - ${n}"

    l=$((l+1))
done

echo -e "${strout}"
```

If 'class' is not a literal string, it might still be of some help. Sorry, you didn't give much information in the OP